# How to add an entry for all next dates once it first appeared

Tags: python, pandas

I have a database that updates on a daily basis. Currently, it only has "active cases" - let's say when the value is 1 or higher.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Date": [
        "2020-04-09", "2020-04-09",
        "2020-04-10", "2020-04-10", "2020-04-10",
        "2020-04-11", "2020-04-11", 
        "2020-04-12", "2020-04-12",
        "2020-04-13", "2020-04-13", "2020-04-13"
    ],
    "ID": [2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
    "Value": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
})
```

---

```
    Date        ID  Value
0   2020-04-09  2   1
1   2020-04-09  3   1
2   2020-04-10  1   1
3   2020-04-10  2   1
4   2020-04-10  3   1
5   2020-04-11  2   1
6   2020-04-11  3   1
7   2020-04-12  2   1
8   2020-04-12  3   1
9   2020-04-13  1   1
10  2020-04-13  2   1
11  2020-04-13  3   1
```

---

So on the `2020-04-10` there could be 3 active cases, but on the following day - only 2, and only these 2 cases would be stored in the database.

What I need is to keep "inactive" ID entries for every next date once it first appeared (but not before) with value 0.

The desired output:

```py
result = pd.DataFrame({
    "Date": [
        "2020-04-09", "2020-04-09",
        "2020-04-10", "2020-04-10", "2020-04-10",
        "2020-04-11", "2020-04-11", "2020-04-11", 
        "2020-04-12", "2020-04-12", "2020-04-12", 
        "2020-04-13", "2020-04-13", "2020-04-13",
    ],
    "ID": [2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
    "Value": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
})
```

---

```
    Date        ID  Value
0   2020-04-09  2   1
1   2020-04-09  3   1
2   2020-04-10  1   1
3   2020-04-10  2   1
4   2020-04-10  3   1
5   2020-04-11  1   0 <- 0 because there were no active cases
6   2020-04-11  2   1
7   2020-04-11  3   1
8   2020-04-12  1   0 <- 0 because there were no active cases
9   2020-04-12  2   1
10  2020-04-12  3   1
11  2020-04-13  1   1 <- nothing changes because it already was there
12  2020-04-13  2   1
13  2020-04-13  3   1
```

And `ID` 1 wasn't added to `2020-04-09`, because it first appeared on `2020-04-10`.

Naturally, I have ~500 unique ID's and daily data starting from January.

Also I need to add some metadata that's connected to the database via ID, but I think I'll hande it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is reshape by `pivot` and then replace missing values to `0` but only for rows if exist at least one non missing value before:

```
df1 = df.pivot('Date','ID','Value')
df2 = (df1.mask(df1.ffill().notna() & df1.isna(), 0)
          .stack()
          .astype(int)
          .reset_index(name='Value'))
print (df2)
          Date  ID  Value
0   2020-04-09   2      1
1   2020-04-09   3      1
2   2020-04-10   1      1
3   2020-04-10   2      1
4   2020-04-10   3      1
5   2020-04-11   1      0
6   2020-04-11   2      1
7   2020-04-11   3      1
8   2020-04-12   1      0
9   2020-04-12   2      1
10  2020-04-12   3      1
11  2020-04-13   1      1
12  2020-04-13   2      1
13  2020-04-13   3      1
```

**Details**:

```
print (df1)
ID            1    2    3
Date                     
2020-04-09  NaN  1.0  1.0
2020-04-10  1.0  1.0  1.0
2020-04-11  NaN  1.0  1.0
2020-04-12  NaN  1.0  1.0
2020-04-13  1.0  1.0  1.0

print (df1.ffill().notna() & df1.isna())
ID              1      2      3
Date                           
2020-04-09  False  False  False
2020-04-10  False  False  False
2020-04-11   True  False  False
2020-04-12   True  False  False
2020-04-13  False  False  False

print (df1.mask(df1.ffill().notna() & df1.isna(), 0))
ID            1    2    3
Date                     
2020-04-09  NaN  1.0  1.0
2020-04-10  1.0  1.0  1.0
2020-04-11  0.0  1.0  1.0
2020-04-12  0.0  1.0  1.0
2020-04-13  1.0  1.0  1.0
```